# Individual/restricted "dashboard" for Icinga Classic

Tags: monitoring, nagios, restriction

Im a student, and having a bachelor thesis, and one of my tasks is to set up a solution where system administrators at local schools should be able to monitor their relevant services and hosts.

Lets say there are a firm that hosts many local schools in a city. The system administrators at the firm, which drifts every server/host loaclly, has fully acces on monitoring all Icinga hosts and services, but system admins and IT service at the schools would like a Icinga monitoring as well. They should not be able to config hosts, just have a overall monitoring for the hosts thay are using.

Is there a solution for this, a restricted/individual monitoring plugin for many individual users?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need enter in cgi.cfg, where user_viewer is a user than you need create before with htpasswd and first defined as contact too.

```
authorized_for_read_only=user_viewer
```

But you need have permissions to modify this. Check before the rest of properties around cgi.cfg, but this place you can get this and more custom things.

Another solution maybe more focus in visualization and custom monitoring is install and config NagVis, Design a simple dashboards. It has a template system then you can reuse a design with differents schools. This solution is nice for managment people because it present a simple monitoring dashboard.